how I can configure MonetDB with pacemaker for high availability solution
I want to configure DRBD/corosync/pacemaker for monetDB as high availability solution, but when I reach the step of pacemaker that configure the resources,  I got below error because no agent for monetDB like (mysql or pgsql).  What should I add, and how I could configure it? , if anyone know please assist?
Error

Error: Agent 'ocf:heartbeat:monetdbd' is not installed or does not provide valid metadata: crm_resource: Metadata query for ocf:heartbeat:monetdbd failed: No such device or address, Error performing operation: No such object, use --force to override
Error: Errors have occurred, therefore pcs is unable to continue

Command :

pcs -f clust_cfg resource create  monetdbd service:heartbeat:monetdb 
mserver="/usr/bin/mserver5"
monetdbd="/usr/bin/monetdbd" dbfarm="/data/monetdb_firstfarm" 
op start interval="0" timeout="120s" 
op stop interval="0" timeout="120s" 
op monitor interval="30s" timeout="30s"


It is solved ,I found how to configure monetdb with pacemaker without having errors that is by dealing with Monetdb as service not as ocf (pacemaker agent ) , by using below command

pcs -f clust_cfg resource create  monet service:monetdbd 
op start interval="0" timeout="120s" 
op stop interval="0" timeout="120s" 
op monitor interval="30s" timeout="30s"
Blockquote

Thanks
